# find a command on $PATH

Tags: path, sh

I'm writing a script, and I need to look up a command on the user's $PATH and get the full path to the command.  The problem is that I don't know what the user's login shell is, or what strange stuff might be in their do files.  I'm using the bourne shell for my simple little script because it needs to run on some older Solaris platforms that might not have bash.

Some implementations of "which" and "whence" will source the user's dot files, and that isn't really portable to all users.  I'd love a simple UNIX utility that would just do the basic job of scanning PATH for an executable and reporting the full path of the first match.

But I'll settle for any /bin/sh solution that is stable for all users.

I'm looking for a solution that is better than writing my own /bin/sh loop that chops up $PATH and searches it one line at a time.  It would seem that this is common enough that there should be an reusable way to do it.

My first approximation of the "long way" is this:

```
   IFS=:
   for i in $PATH; do
      if [ -x $i/$cmd ]; then
          echo $i/$cmd
      fi
   done
```

Is there something simpler and portable?

Comment: Do you need to worry about all of their dot files, etc? At the time the script is run, won't the user already be in their shell? Aka, the files will already be sourced?

Comment: The problem is if my .profile is set up only for ksh, and my sh script ends up sourcing it as a part of running the 'which' or 'whence' commands.  The 'whence' man page on my Solaris 11 box refers to a ksh built-in.  I'm looking for a portable way of doing this.

Comment: One good answer would be if someone could promise me that the 'whence' built-in is reliable, doesn't depend on any dot files, and is portable to Linux and Solaris implementations of '/bin/sh'.  Another good answer is a pointer to a different command I've never heard of that meets the same criteria.

Comment: The 'type' command might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: As a comment on your approximation, while it is inferior to using `type`, it is a fairly good and succinct script in and of itself.  However, it should take care to set its exit code to 0 in case of success (command found) and 1 otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

The answer seems to be the 'type' built-in.

```
% /bin/sh
$ type ls
ls is /bin/ls
```

Comment: Very neat find!  Does yours sometimes say [command] is hashed?  `$ type find find is hashed (/usr/bin/find)`

Comment: I haven't seen output like that.  I did see this in ksh: ls is a tracked alias for /bin/ls.  I'm only concerned about the output of shells that might get run under the name of /bin/sh.  Since that's what I'm using on my #! line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `whereis` command will work for you?

```
whereis -b -B `echo $PATH | sed 's/:/ /g'` -f [commands]
```

e.g. on my computer, this works:

```
whereis -b -B `echo $PATH | sed 's/:/ /g'` -f find man fsc
```

And results in:

```
find: /usr/bin/find
man: /usr/bin/man
fsc: /opt/FSharp-2.0.0.0/bin/fsc.exe /opt/FSharp-2.0.0.0/bin/fsc
```

One caveat from the `whereis` man page:

```
   Since whereis uses chdir(2V) to run faster, pathnames given
   with the -M, -S, or -B must be full; that is, they must begin
   with a `/'.
```

Comment: 'whereis' doesn't seem to be available on my Solaris box unless I add the /usr/ucb package.  It seems that the biggest trick for writing a portable script is to understand what subset of external binaries it's okay to use.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered in details here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then.  Bottom line: use `command -v ls`.